# How to make auto scaling axis ticks fade in/out?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to fade ticks in/out on the auto scaling axis when I zoom in and out.  I got them to fade in with js and css, but I think/hope there is a better way, and this is only for fade in, not fade out

```
 let nodes = document.querySelector('#bhc-container').querySelectorAll('.axis');
        if (nodes.length) {
            nodes.forEach(node => {
                let ticks = node.querySelectorAll('.tick');
                ticks.forEach(tick => {
                    let classes = tick.getAttribute('class');
                    tick.setAttribute('class', `${classes} fade-in`);
                });
            });
        }
```

In the brush callback where I'm calling the axis, I added a transition which sort of works, it does fade the ticks in and out, but it also causes the axis position to lag behind the chart, which sucks.

```
chart.select('.axis--TVD')
            .transition()
            .delay(350)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .call(chart.elements.svg.yAxisTVD);
```

I tried an `enter()` on the above code, that didn't work either. Is there a way to select the ticks when they enter and exit? If so I can use a class to fade them in and out.   Or is there a way to apply the `transition()` only to those specific ticks?

--

Update:

In this example: 
https://blockbuilder.org/zp1112/0168db9dff4f5a42d7e7b9689e725f98

Can anyone make the ticks fade in and out while zooming?

Comment: Does this [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/678935d06d4601c25cb141bacd4068ce) help you? Isn't it the fading you are after?

Comment: @altocumulus . Thanks for the replay, but unfortunately it doesn't work.   When I zoom, the position of the axis and ticks lags behind the data on the chart and is a bad user experience.